# JavaScript not showing remaining characters, but works on other pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So I have implemented JavaScript which notifies the user how much characters a user has remaining.

Here is my textarea and where the feedback should be shown:

```
<form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
   <textarea id="txtarea" name='msg' rows='2' maxlength='255' cols='80' placeholder=' Share a thought...'></textarea>
   <input type='submit' name='send' value='Share'/>
</form>

// this is where the feedback should be shown...
<div id="textarea_feed">  </div>
```

And here is the JavaScript to achieve the desired functionality:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var text_max = 255;
                $('#textarea_feed').html(text_max + ' characters remaining');

                $('#txtarea').keyup(function() {
                    var text_length = $('#txtarea').val().length;
                    var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;

                    $('#textarea_feed').html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining');
                });
            });
        </script>
```

I have the exact same form and JavaScript layout on `profile_page.php`, and it works there, but for some reason, I no text is being shown in the `div`. I know the div is not hidden behind any other divs because I have tested with sample content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you are including a jQuery script tag in your html.
It works for me when I add the CDN.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aeuzfLao/

Comment: Ahh silly me, I had it commented out for some weird reason! Nevertheless, it worked, thanks!

Comment: Happy to help, have fun!